# 3 Scaling images inline

Tags: css, html

So, I created an image in photoshop that is 1920x1080 and I've spliced it into sections, so that the images that require a link can have an javascript tag attached to them for a link.

I want the images to scale depending on the type of monitor you're using, as long as you're in a 16:9 ratio. The problem I'm having, is in regards to the way the images align 3 in a row. Either the 3rd image in the row gets pushed down, for sections with 3 images. Or, the image is the full size 1920x1080, but no scaling and gaps between images.

My HTML looks like this:

```
<main>
    <section>
        <img src="images/NuclearFuelCycle1.png"/>
    </section>
    <section>
        <div><img id="1" src="images/NuclearFuelCycle2.png"/><span style="cursor:pointer" onclick="openMining()"><img id="2" src="images/NuclearFuelCycle3.png"/></span><img id="3" src="images/NuclearFuelCycle4.png"/></div>
    </section>
    <section>
        <img src="images/NuclearFuelCycle5.png"/></section>
    <section>
        <img src="images/NuclearFuelCycle6.png"/><span style="cursor:pointer" onclick="openConversion()"><img src="images/NuclearFuelCycle7.png"/></span><img src="images/NuclearFuelCycle8.png"/>
    </section>
    <section>
        <img src="images/NuclearFuelCycle9.png"/>
    </section>
    <section>
        <img src="images/NuclearFuelCycle10.png"/><span style="cursor:pointer" onclick="openEnrichment()"><img src="images/NuclearFuelCycle11.png"/></span><img src="images/NuclearFuelCycle12.png"/>
    </section>
    <section>
        <img src="images/NuclearFuelCycle13.png"/>
    </section>
    <section>
        <img src="images/NuclearFuelCycle14.png"/><span style="cursor:pointer" onclick="openReactor()"><img src="images/NuclearFuelCycle15.png"/></span><img src="images/NuclearFuelCycle16.png"/>
    </section>
    <section>
        <img src="images/NuclearFuelCycle17.png"/>
    </section>
    <section>
        <img src="images/NuclearFuelCycle18.png"/><span style="cursor:pointer" onclick="openSpentFuel()"><img src="images/NuclearFuelCycle19.png"/></span><img src="images/NuclearFuelCycle20.png"/>
    </section>
    <section>
        <img src="images/NuclearFuelCycle21.png"/>
    </section>
    <section>
        <img src="images/NuclearFuelCycle22.png"/><span style="cursor:pointer" onclick="openFuelFabrication()"><img src="images/NuclearFuelCycle23.png"/></span><img src="images/NuclearFuelCycle24.png"/>
    </section>
    <section>
        <img src="images/NuclearFuelCycle25.png"/></section>
    <section>
        <img src="images/NuclearFuelCycle26.png"/><span style="cursor:pointer" onclick="openStorageDisposal()"><img src="images/NuclearFuelCycle27.png"/></span><img src="images/NuclearFuelCycle28.png"/>
    </section>
    <section>
        <img src="images/NuclearFuelCycle29.png"/>
    </section>
</main>
```

My CSS looks like this:

```
* {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    border: 0;
    border-collapse: collapse;
}

body {
    max-width: 100% !important;
    height: auto;
}

main {
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 10px;
}

section div img{
    width: auto;
}
```

Some of this code is not useful... It's me experimenting to try and create a solution. Any help would be greatly appreciated, I have to submit this in 2 days P

Comment: instead of pasting your code directly inside textarea, Try creating the code snippet using SO feature. And it would be easier to help if you could upload your images as well and link them in here. Stack Overflow provides option for image uploading as well as code-fiddler. Check the buttons in toolbar;

Comment: are you using bootstrap?

Comment: The sensible thing is to not scale according the monitor size because the monitor size include the entire browser window (title bar, menu bar etc). Also you are assuming everyone will always have their window to full width (monitor size). You must scale according to window size inside the browser

Comment: I don't mind if I have to create padding around it to keep it centered, but here is the url so you can look at it: http://arielgoodall.com/

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding correctly your sliced image segments are repositioning incorrectly as the browser window resizes.

Rather than slicing up your image and using javascript, why not try a pure HTML solution and use the `<map>` tag to insert your links at various parts of the image?

Here's a [Fiddle](https://fiddle.jshell.net/f612qdvm/1/) demonstrating a scalable HTML image map (uses the [image-map-resizer](https://github.com/davidjbradshaw/image-map-resizer) plugin)

You can learn more about image maps [here](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_map.asp).

Comment: Hi MadGab!

Here is the website with all available code: http://arielgoodall.com/ You can see what's happening.

Comment: Also, map doesn't allow for scaling

Comment: @Mantagonist scaling can be added with a simple jQuery plugin. I've added a Fiddle to my answer that uses the map element and scales...you can click on the steam generator or control room icons to see the result. Hope this helps you out.

Comment: That is really cool MadGab...I assumed you couldn't do it, because the coordinates would be lost, but I guess if there is a will, there is a way. That might have been the nicest solution to this whole problem.

Comment: @Mantagonist Happy to help! Please be sure to choose an answer, and good luck with your project.

Answer (score 0):

The 'spaces' problem is most likely due to the way `display:inline` works, which is what an image and a span is. Any newlines, etc get treated as a space char. An easy fix could be something that uses `display:flex`.

The second (and main part) of your problem is that you want to scale based on width. A little bit of javascript and use of `transform: scale(...)` fixes that. Below is a snippet (which can't show resizing), so here's a CodePen too: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/PpXpwO

```js
window.onresize = resizer;
resizer();
function resizer() {
  console.log("resized")
  var _main = document.querySelector("main");
  var image_width = 600; // the original image width
  var ratio  = _main.offsetWidth/image_width;
  _main.style.transform = "scale("+ratio+")";
};
```

```css
main {
  transform-origin: 0 0;
}
section {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: nowrap;
}
section * {
  flex: 0 0 auto;
  display: block;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <section>
    <img src="https://placehold.it/600x150g" />
  </section>
  <section>
    <img id="1" src="https://placehold.it/100x150" />
    <a style="cursor:pointer" onclick="openMining()"><img id="2" src="https://placehold.it/300x150/370000" /></a>
    <img id="3" src="https://placehold.it/200x150" />
  </section>
  <section>
    <img src="https://placehold.it/600x150g" />
  </section>
</main>
```

Comment: This was awesome! I enjoyed placing this into my code and learning it. I'm confused by the width variable in the script area: var image_width = 600; // the max-image width Am I telling it the width of the screen or the max an image can be?

I've decided to give you my entire website here: http://arielgoodall.com/

I still can't figure out how to make it stay in the ratio.

Comment: Ohhh, the 600 is for the max it will expand to, but what if I want it to shrink based on monitor size as well? How is this accomplished?

Comment: @Mantagonist, replace this with 1920 for your image size, and all will be good. The 600 is not a 'max', but the _default_ (I've updated the code to reflect this). Everything will scale appropriately (either up or down, there is no limit). Don't forget to upvote and/or 'mark as answer' if answered.

Comment: It's still not doing it I'm afraid. I've changed the number to 1920 as well. 

I'll upload what I have done to the arielgoodall.com site

I'm assuming the main offset width - image width is the thing that is setting the max, but for some odd reason, it's not scaling down

Comment: Okay, I'm confused.. Only after I hit alt on my keyboard did a change occur to the content in the window. Until that point, not changes would occur when I first open the site. I'm also getting a funky thing, where Mozilla is accepting my bg color for the overlay, but chrome and ie are not.